# I want to access a logout function from my nav bar on any page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an authentication process, where I want to be able to access the logout function on any page from my Index.html nav bar, but for some reason I'm not reaching the scope.

I have my app.js controller, but when I switch views, that controller is replaced. So I put the function below on the new view:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
    AuthService.logout();
    $state.go('login');
};
```

But when I call it from my index.html nav I can't access the function.

I'm using ui-router.

So my layout is like this:

```
<html>
    <nav></nav>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
<html>
```

Where would you put and access a logout function that can be accessed from anywhere?

Comment: please provide a complete example.

Comment: if your nav bar is a directive/component and it has its own scope, it will never reach that method. but first please provide what you have so far.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views - Use a nested state from a parent template state with the logout button. Then resolve in the logout button's functions.

Comment: @SummerDeveloper, Thanks! I was just in the middle of putting something up on Plunker, but you hit the nail on the head. I think wrapping all m views under a parent and calling the function from the parent control is the right answer. The one think I want to figure out now is how to modularize my views. For example, each of my views has it's own js file that I include a config file for. So I just need to make sure I know how to break out the child views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the navigation controller is not necessary the parent of all other controllers/views, it seems like an overkill to the problem. They can be siblings or they don't have any parent-child relationship at all using nested state.

If you are only accessing this logout method from your navbar *only*, you would just need to create/declare that controller in `ng-controller` directive as such:

**nav.html**

```
<nav ng-controller="NavigationCtrl" />
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li ng-click="logout()">Logout</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If you are accessing this method from anywhere in your app, I'd create a directive and listen to a `$rootScope` event like such:

**logout.directive.js**

```
.directive('logout', logoutMethod);

logoutMethod.$inject = [
    '$rootScope',
    'AuthService',
    '$state'
];

function logoutMethod(
    $rootScope,
    AuthService,
    $state
){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function() {
            $rootScope.$on('initiateLogout', function() {
                AuthService.logout(); 
                $state.go('logout');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and then somewhere in your application,

```
$rootScope.$emit('initiateLogout');
```